# .Jar runs fine on Windows but throws exception on MAC

Tags: java, macos, javafx, cross-platform

im experiencing a weird problem, and i can't even properly use my Exception stack trace, as it looks like! the problem is produced in the JavaFX Methods itself.

This is my usage: Im creating a ObservableArrayList and want to show it in a LineChart.

This is how i create / feed my ObservableArrayList with data:

```
  public void showDetails(Spieler selected)
{
    ObservableList<Data<String, Number>> epData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ObservableList<Data<String, Number>> tpData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ObservableList<Data<String, Number>> awpData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < selected.getEp().size(); i++)
    {
        String currentDateVal = selected.getEinsaetze().get(i).toString();
        epData.add(new Data<String, Number>(currentDateVal, selected.getEp().get(i)));
        tpData.add(new Data<String, Number>(currentDateVal, selected.getTp().get(i)));
        int curAwp = m.calculateAWP(selected.getEp().get(i), selected.getTp().get(i));
        awpData.add(new Data<String, Number>(currentDateVal, curAwp));
    }
    dv.setData(epData, tpData, awpData, selected, m.getBenoetigteAWP(selected.getCurrentStaerke() + 1));
}
```

and my SetData(where the exception is eventually thrown) looks like this:

```
public void setData(ObservableList<Data<String, Number>> epData, ObservableList<Data<String, Number>> tpData, ObservableList<Data<String, Number>> awpData, Spieler selected, int benoetigt)
{
    if(epChart.getData() != null)
    {
        epChart.getData().clear();
        epChart.setData(null);
    }
    if(tpChart.getData() != null)
    {
        tpChart.getData().clear();
        tpChart.setData(null);
    }
    if(awpChart.getData() != null)
    {
        awpChart.getData().clear();
        awpChart.setData(null);
    }
    epChart.setData(epData);
    tpChart.setData(tpData);
    awpChart.setData(awpData);
[... some Label formatting and stuff]
}
```

The thing now is, it runs fine either in my IDE or in my compiled runnable Jar, everything works fine.
But when a friend of mine (whom i'm coding this little tool for) uses it on OSX, it throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 5
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
at javafx.scene.chart.XYChart$Series.getItem(XYChart.java:1628)
at javafx.scene.chart.LineChart.dataItemRemoved(LineChart.java:305)
at javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.dataItemsChanged(XYChart.java:497)
at javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.access$2300(XYChart.java:93)
at javafx.scene.chart.XYChart$Series$1.onChanged(XYChart.java:1457)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:164)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:482)
at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:205)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.clear(ObservableListWrapper.java:157)
at soccerCharts.detail.DetailView.setData(DetailView.java:129)
at soccerCharts.detail.DetailPresenter.showDetails(DetailPresenter.java:43)
```

(Line 129 mentioned in the Exception is where i clear the existing ObservableList).

I myself am not using any Indices so i really dont get, why it throws an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Looking forward to your advice :)

Regards, definately not a professional coder ;)

Comment: I've had this recently on Windows. My solution was to only use setData, no clearing.

Comment: Well, my posted solution is already a tried workaround. Before that, i only had setData, and then the exception would be pointed towards the "setData" instruction.

Comment: Tried to go through the exception stack, which is thrown. The eventhandler notices a change of selected Item in the table. Then it proceeds to call my listener, who then fires the "showDetails" method with the selected "Spieler" as parameter. Then it calls "setData" and upon the first call of some of the XY.Series the index goes out of bounds. But i  have no idea why :/

Comment: Probably some race condition. And definitiely a bug in JavaFX. I doubt that it solves the problem, but you could try disabling the animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as [Roland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1844265/roland) said, it "solved" the problem to disable the animation on the table as a whole.

```
table.setAnimated(false);
```

The exception stopped all i'm recieving now is

```
Mär 16, 2015 6:17:08 AM com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow addTrailingCells
INFO: index exceeds maxCellCount. Check size calculations for class javafx.scene.control.TableRow
```

Which i guess is just a warning. It works fine now. Thanks for everyone looking at it, and thanks to Roland.

Hopefully this will help someone sometime.
Greetings